# TabBar customization in ios4 doesnt work in ios5

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, customization, uitabbar

In my app i want to customize the pattern of the tabbar, but my deployment target is ios4, so i am using the code bellow in the appDidBecomeActive in the appDelegate.m to do this:

```
CGRect frameTab = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 49);
UIView *viewTab = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frameTab];
UIImage *tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bar.png"];
UIColor *tabColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:tabBarBackground];
[viewTab setBackgroundColor:tabColor];
[[myTabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:viewTab atIndex:0];
```

When i run the app using the 4.3 simulator, it works properly, but when i simulate in ios5, it doesnt work, the tab goes back to black.. any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in iOS 5 there's new `backgroundImage` property in UITabBar class and you should use it:

```
UIImage *tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bar.png"];
if ([[myTabBarController tabBar] respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:)]){
     [[myTabBarController tabBar] setBackgroundImage: tabBarBackground];
}
else{
    // If no backgroundImage property (pre iOS5) use your old code
    CGRect frameTab = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 49);
    UIView *viewTab = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frameTab];
    UIColor *tabColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:tabBarBackground];
    [viewTab setBackgroundColor:tabColor];
    [[myTabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:viewTab atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: so this code wont complain about incompatibility running on ios 4 because the if statement blocks ios4 from entering and setting it, am I correct?

Comment: but the [[myTabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:viewTab atIndex:0]; might be considered to be an access to the private parts of the system?

Comment: @Ondrej, it is not exactly private API so it is probably appstore safe . But as you see it is rather fragile, relies on internal implementation and can break with each ios release, so for newer iOS versions you should use other solutions